# Adding third-party JS to CMS page

Tags: javascript

Is it really difficult to add third-party JS to a global CMS template? For example if there was a library that loaded its own JQuery with no conflict and also called a third-party API is this difficult to do or impossible?

Is there documentation?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your use case and provide details on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: For example adding Optimizely.js to the global template. Is this possible? If so is it difficult and why? I don't have Tridion just trying to evaluate technically.

Comment: Global template mean? in your  development solution or you want to update in Tridion CM interface.

Comment: Is this related to SDL Tridion at all?

Comment: I do see this as a Tridion question from EKet, who's considering the system. For context, what (types of) systems are you comparing Tridion to and who would be managing these JavaScript references? This is fairly easy for template developers, but needs to be set up if managed by "regular" editors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick answer yes, there are many ways to refer the libraries. It depends upon where you need to refer and your use case like is it on content management end or on the actual web pages. Here are a couple:

1. [GUI Extension](https://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/GUIextensionIn8steps.aspx) In GUI extension you can open any MVC based app or any other app where any JQuery library or any other library can be loaded without any issue. Also, you can call any API from the same. This is in CME context (meaning it will open from CME).
2. Actual page on a Website: To enable the same, you can include any library files in page template directly which will be included in your actual web pages which are rendered using the given page template

A clearer question helps bring the right answer which you might be looking for.

Comment: Just looking for those options - thanks Vipin.